# Apache and Rewrite url problem

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

i have some problems with url rewrite

i need trasform that url

```
News/?a=shownews&id=53
```

to

```
index.php?m=News&a=shownews&id=53
```

i tried to make it:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/\?(.+?)$ index.php?m=$1&$2 [R]
```

but it dosen't work, could do you help me to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
I take that back - apparently it is possible to do this in your case

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ index.php?m=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: yes just after i made that 

    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?$ index.php?m=$1 [QSA]

 i saw your reply thx all anyway

Answer (score 0):

Apache cannot use $_GET parameters to build the new URL ; you'll have to change the structure of the URL.

Comment: O.o i don't want use $_GET i just want split that 
    News/?a=shownews&id=53
into
    $1 = News
    $2 = a=shownews&id=53 
to combine them into index.php?m=News&a=shownews&id=53

Answer (score 0):

From Apache's documentation:

> By default, the query string is passed
>   through unchanged. You can, however,
>   create URLs in the substitution string
>   containing a query string part. Simply
>   use a question mark inside the
>   substitution string to indicate that
>   the following text should be
>   re-injected into the query string.
>   When you want to erase an existing
>   query string, end the substitution
>   string with just a question mark. To
>   combine new and old query strings, use
>   the [QSA] flag.

Using the [QSA] flag you can rebiuld your URL as you have, and the existing query string parameters will be appended, or passed through.

Hope this helps.